# matching values of two textboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've two text boxes with different `ng-models`. They fill up using a `$http.get` request on click of a button.

Lets say:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name.title" />
<input type="text" ng-model="name.surname" />
```

These get filled up just fine from my JSON data.

The value of my `name.title` can sometimes be like "abc (123)". If a user edits this, I want the `name.surname` to become the part inside the (). If the user removes "abc (123)" and just types in 123, then 123 should reflect in `name.surname`.

I've tried various combinations using `ng-blur` and `ng-change` but nothing so far has worked for me.

Its just one two textboxes so no point writing a new directive.

How do I do this?

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: You mean to say, initally these two text boxes will have its own value, after rendering once the user happens to edit the first text box then the second will get changed accordingly right?

Comment: Yes David, that's exactly what I mean. Can you help?

Comment: So,in the paranthesis it is always integer?

Comment: You could say a string rather. Because it can be something like 12.3.5. something like release value of my product title. Although, there wouldn't ever be alphabetical character, words, etc. @RIYAJKHAN

Answer (score 0):

I asume that your using angular 1.x.

You could have a watch over name.
something like in you

```js
$scope.$watch('[name.title, name.surname]', function(newValue, prevValue) {
     if (newValue === prevValue) {
        return;
     }
     //Here you put your logic and update the models.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this overwrites my data which loads from a JSON file. Is there a way this starts functioning only after I edit name.title? I've created a sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qUImGa4OctOxEUJFd3HU?p=preview). This does not have the JSON file calling here but I've used the data directly.